freeipa system account list in web ui
In a fresh freeipa installation, I created a systemaccount using
ldapadd -x -D 'cn=Directory Manager' -w Password -f user.ldif

where user.ldif contained
dn: uid=gitea,cn=sysaccounts,cn=etc,dc=dyumnin,dc=com
changetype: add
objectclass: account
objectclass: simplesecurityobject
uid: gitea
userPassword: password
passwordExpirationTime: 20380119031407Z
nsIdleTimeout: 0


this shows up when I execute ldapsearch,
# gitea, sysaccounts, etc, dyumnin.com
dn: uid=gitea,cn=sysaccounts,cn=etc,dc=dyumnin,dc=com
objectClass: account
objectClass: simplesecurityobject
objectClass: top
uid: gitea
userPassword:: ....

But I am not able to see it in the web ui. Users list.
What steps need to be taken to access and manage the sysaccounts in webui?

FreeIPA has no 'native' integration with so-called 'sysaccounts'. There is only a suggestion how those can be created. As a result, there is no IPA API to handle them and no support for them in either command line interface (ipa CLI tool) nor in Web UI.
